# Login inside dropdown closes when field is required and when modal with alert about input pops up

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, dropdown

I have this login form inside a Bootstrap 4 dropdown. When I click the dropdown pops up.

The problem is, if a field is required it just closes without any required message (HTML5 validation). And also when a message pops up from input validation (I also use a modal to show that error). How can the dropdown stay open while the modal opens and keep the input focused where the user left off (or maybe that's too much extra).

I tried using the dropdown - keep-open class with code that I found a lot on Google/Stack Overflow. But nothing kept the dropdown to close I don't know why (just added the class to dropdown and some jQuery code added).

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<a id="dropdownMenuLogin" class="nav-link badge" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Login</a>

<ul class='dropdown'>
  <a class='welcome'>
    <a class='badge badge-pill badge-primary' data-toggle='dropdown' align='center'>Welcome<i class='welcome-user-arrow down'></i></a></a>
  <li class='dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-welcome'>
    <a class='dropdown-item' href='account.php'><b>Account overview</b></a>
    <div class='dropdown-divider'></div><a class='dropdown-item' href='account.php'>Account</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

What can I try to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Wrapped my button and drop-menu inside a div named `keep-open`.

```
  $('.keep-open').on({
      "shown.bs.dropdown": function() { this.closable = false; },
      "click":             function() { this.closable = false; },
      "hide.bs.dropdown":  function() { return this.closable; }
});
```

This works.